# Using separate fuzz and octave pedals

Tags: guitar-effects

I'm curious as to why a person would use a fuzz octave pedal like let's say the EHX Octavix over a standard fuzz pedal with some sort of octave effect with it.

Will there be any noticeable improvement in the quality of tone if you use separate fuzz and octave pedals versus one box like some sort of octave fuzz?

Comment: Depends on the brands. The bonus to that pedal is that EHX already does the best octave pedals around as for EHX fuzz.....lets not go there. The problem with fuzz octave pedals is that the fuzz is added to the signal before the octaves. Which just sounds like you've have a bad distortion pedal with internal feedback problems. Yuk! Definitely go 2 separate pedals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using separate pedals almost always gives you more granular control over each part of the effect, plus the ability to change the order of the effects - an octave after the fuzz gives you a very different sound to octave before fuzz.

It's not an improvement in tone, necessarily, but it is different, and gives you more options.